# Add GroupBy on query dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, x++

I have this consult to show all the data on a grid, and I need to show only one per element, for that reason I think I need a groupBy or distinct. I'm really new :c

This is my code:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    filterGrid = this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(Table)).addRange(fieldNum(Table,Field));
}
```

I need a GroupBy here but I dont know how to put or where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be closer than you think, edit the datasource `init` method to look like this:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(Table)).addGroupByField(fieldNum(Table,Field));
}
```

Comment: Hello @Jan B, I cant add addGroupBy because I have `filterGrid =` :c, I have a ComboBox on a grid and send a ValueStr() to ExecuteQuery and that send to that Init on the same DataSourse, thank you for your time Jan !

Comment: You *can* filter on the field you are grouping on.They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I was sure I tried that before, but now is working, just change `addGroupByField` instead  `addGroupBy` Thank you so much It was my mistake, it works perfect !!